# How do I select value and options (label names) are invisible from react-select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am new to React. I'm using `react-select` and I've used the following code. The dropdown is displayed but I'm unable to see names and unable to view after selecting.

```
<Select
  variant="outlined"
  margin="normal"
  fullWidth
  value={this.state.selected}
  options={RewardAutomationsList}
  name="selected"
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  placeholder='None'
>
  {RewardAutomationsList.map((option) => (
    <option key={option.id} value ={option.name} label={option.name}>
      {option.name}
    </option>
  ))}
</Select>
```

```js
handleChange = event => {
  this.setState({
    selected: event.name
  });
};
```

The `RewardAutomationsList` looks like this:

```sh
RewardAutomationsList:
  0:{name: "TEST 1 (INR 100)", id: "123"}
  1:{name: "test 2 (INR 250)", id: "456"}
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

same npm package use like this block code.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import Select from 'react-select'
    
    const options = [
      { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
      { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
      { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
    ]
    
    const MyComponent = () => (
      <Select options={options} />
    )
```

Comment: This is fine.anything wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

`react-select` accepts an array of objects having `label` and `value` keys. Your option objects in `RewardAutomationsList` have `id` and `name` keys, so it can't be displayed. You need to change them.

Also, when you subscribe to change events with `react-select`'s `onChange` prop, the callback function you provide receives the `selectedOption`, not the `event`.

The following should work:

```
const RewardAutomationsList = [
  { label: "TEST 1 (INR 100)", value: "123" },
  { label: "test 2 (INR 250)", value: "456" },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: null,
  }

  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: selectedOption,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Select
          fullWidth
          margin="normal"
          name="selected"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={RewardAutomationsList}
          placeholder="None"
          value={this.state.selected}
          variant="outlined"
        />
        {/* It's not necessary and it's only here to show the current state */}
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```